# display: inline-block leaves gap with respect to height after div element

Tags: html, css

I have a div and an image in one div. Parent div has the background color. `display: inline-block` is given to both child div and the image.

```
<div style="background-color: black;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 105px; background-color: #27ae60; margin: 0;"></div>
    <img style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px;" src="http://cdn01.coupondunia.in/sitespecific/media/generated/merchantlogos/logo_5e29580_97.jpg?v=1413531812" />
</div>
```

jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/hv9szL92/2/

[image]

Gap below ebay image and green block must be removed. Thanks

Comment: Can you opplz update your fiddle your image is not visible there...also the solution would be to remove and adjust the padding

Comment: @TusharGupta doesn't matter. Just tell me how to remove black gap below the green block.

Comment: margin-bottom: -4px;add to both the green div and the image

Comment: It worked. Consider posting as an answer.

Comment: Negative margin + magic number ... seems a bit dirty to me

Comment: Never mind....reputation is just illusive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gap is because you set child elements as `display: inline-block`, and inline/inline-block elements respect white spaces, including new-line characters.

The simplest fix is to set zero `font-size` on the parent container in order to make those white spaces zero sized.

```
<div style="background-color: black; font-size: 0;">
    /* content unchanged */
</div>
```

Remember to reset `font-size` back to some reasonable value for any nested element if you need to display text in them.

And it's better not to use inline styles, but I assume this is just an example in your case.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hv9szL92/4/

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: @sodawillow 's answer below is probably what most people will want to do. vertical-align top fixes mosto f this white space issue with display-inline: block

Answer (score 4):

As asked by OP, "Gap below ebay image and green block must be removed. Thanks"

http://jsfiddle.net/hv9szL92/5/

set the vertical-align property on the image and you're done (see [Get rid of space underneath inline-block image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612380/get-rid-of-space-underneath-inline-block-image)) :

```
<img style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px 0px; vertical-align: top;" src="http://cdn01.coupondunia.in/sitespecific/media/generated/merchantlogos/logo_5e29580_97.jpg?v=1413531812"  />
```

As for the green block, just remove the nested div element

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit the margin of your `img`

```
<div style="background-color: black;" >
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 105px; background-color: #27ae60; margin: 0;" ></div>
                <img style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px; margin-bottom: -3.1px;margin-left: -13.5px;" src="http://cdn01.coupondunia.in/sitespecific/MEDIA/generated/merchantlogos/logo_5e29580_97.jpg?v=1413531812"  />
</div>
```

Giving the image a negative margin should prove to be helpful

Any problems , let me know

Comment: Worked for you? It doesn't work for me. Anyways other solutions worked. Thank you.

Comment: @sailesh it works in the jsfiddle provided, please try again and let me know

Answer (score 1):

**Properly aligned and formatted using CSS-tables and Unordered List.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvGJqq**

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="green-block"></li>
    <li id="logo-wrap"><img id="logo" src="http://cdn01.coupondunia.in/sitespecific/media/generated/merchantlogos/logo_5e29580_97.jpg?v=1413531812" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

By using CSS tables you are able to use 'vertical-align: bottom;' to align the image with the bottom of the css cell.

Structure as follows:
 - div#container [display: inline-table]
  - ul [display: table-row]
   - li [display: table-cell, vertical-align:bottom]
    - img#logo [display: block, vertical-align:bottom]
Its pure css, but the same concept besides table layout creating from the mid 90's.

```
/* css reset */

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* css */

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-table;
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
}

#green-block {
  width: 20px;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #27ae60;
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
}

#logo-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

A really nice article out lying many of the concepts used for CSS tables.
http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero