# Small white bar at the bottom of my html/css website?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code an index.html file to put into a github repository so that i can publish a static html website on github pages using css and html. I just realized today that there has been a 2px high footer on my page this entire time. I thought that this would be a simple fix, as I just googled my issue to find that many people had the same problem. After 2 hours of trying different solutions, I still have no idea what is causing the footer to be there, or how to get rid of it. I have ruled out the CSS code as the culprit, since if I go into codepen and delete all the CSS code, the white footer is still there. This is my first project using html and css, so I can't seem to really formulate a solution for myself.

Here is a link to it in codepen (also CSS is below): https://codepen.io/B0xTurtleGames/pen/BaMWboX

```
body, html 
{ 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#0000ff,#00008b);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
margin: 0;
/*height: 100%; */
height: 100%;
width: 100%; 
padding: 0;
cursor:url(https://i.postimg.cc/KvSw4f0x/pixil-frame-0-6.png), auto;
}
```

Here is the footer im talking about (hard to circle it on a school chromebook, tell me if you still have no idea where it is)
[image: Footer circled in red]
(the footer isn't white with the gradient, but I can't put any svg elements on it like i want to for some reason)

I am very new to web-based programming languages, so if anyone has a solution (preferably with an explanation) that would be amazing. Please ask for more information if that helps you solve this.

Also excuse the seizure-inducing color i have some refinements to make before publishing

Here is what I have already tried:

1. Setting the height and width attributes of the body, html{} tag in CSS to 100vh and 100vw respectively
2. setting the margin and padding to 0
3. Whatever this is:

```
<style>
header { border-bottom: none ! important; }
footer { border-top: none ! important; }
</style>
```

4. setting the margin-bottom attribute to a negative value
5. setting the min-height attribute in CSS to 100%

Comment: Could we see at least a small replica of the html?

Comment: @VictoryOsiobe, does the codepen link not work?

Comment: @VictoryOsiobe I put an image in the post so you can see the footer, it isn't white with the linear gradient, sorry about that

Comment: We need a [mcve] here, not on another site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display` property is set to `inline` by default, which often causes extra space below elements. Changing to `block` will eliminate unwanted space around the svg. You can read more about the display property here: [CSS: display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

If you want a better explanation here are some readings:

1. [removing white space](https://mor10.com/removing-white-space-image-elements-inline-elements-descenders/#:%7E:text=The%20white%20space%20displayed%20below,and%20inline%20elements%20have%20descenders.)
2. [extra space in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)
3. [space underneath img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath)
4. [inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612380/get-rid-of-space-underneath-inline-block-image)